# matconvnet classification training last layer (softmax)?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, convolution, conv-neural-network, softmax

I would like to retrain the vgg-imagenet-f network to do classification (rather than direct image comparison, which is what I have done with my own network). 
The downloaded network however is a deployment net, and doesn't have a loss layer included. As I've not done classification training before, I'm a bit stumped as to how to design this last layer. I expect it will be something like this:

```
layer.name = 'loss' ;
layer.type = 'custom' ;
layer.forward = @forward ;
layer.backward = @backward ;
layer.class = [] ;
```

but I don't know what my @forward and @backward functions should be. Should they be softmax?
Of note, I have a imdb with about 10k images, corresponding labels, and an ID element with unique numbers running 1 - 10k. 
Thanks for any help, or any links to a sample of the way one should construct this layer in matconvnet/matlab!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own network adjusting the filters accordingly, since you want to 'retrain' vgg instead of initializing the weights with random numbers you can adapt your classification network using trained filers from downloaded network. The last layer could be softmaxloss
http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/mfiles/vl_nnsoftmaxloss/